# force reload of aspx page from silverlight xaml

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I've a Silverlight application that is called from a asp .net project. I have a link in the silverlight project that brings the user back to the asp.net project. I do not want this to happen in a new window.

At the moment, it returns me to the cached page. I want to force a reload of it.

Currently onclick event of the link invokes the following code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://ipaddress/menu.aspx"));
```

Any suggestions on how I could enforce menu.aspx to reload when called?

I found a solution..

**SOLUTION**

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://ipaddress/menu.aspx?"));

This results in the page being reloaded....

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
HtmlPage.Document.Submit()
```

It should work if your .aspx target page you wish to reload is the current page.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I eventually found solution: by adding a '?' to the end of the url.. I'll update main post.